# How to make jekyll process `{%` structure in included code snippet

Tags: latex, markdown, jekyll

In my latex snippets I have lines like

```
\somecommand{% comments about this command
    <params>,
    ...
}
```

If I include this code snippet in a markdown file like

````
$ cat jekyll-processed.md 
---
header: info
---

```tex
    \somecommand{% comment about his command
        <params>,
        ...
    }
```
````

Jekyll complains about incomplete `{%`. It is very common  to use this structure `{%` to ignore extra space/newlines and comments. Is there any of having them processed by jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render `{%` inside you `*.md` file, you'll need to tell Jekyll to escape it. For that purpose the `{% raw %}` notation exists.

So in your context:

```
tex
    \somecommand{% raw %}{%{% endraw %}
```